# Como crear un marcador de turnos

Tags: php, javascript, html

Trato de crear una página en donde se pueda llevar el conteo de puntos de cierta actividad. Para lograr esto uso dos archivos html `formulario.php` y `marcador.php`.

El `formulario.php` contiene, como su nombre lo indica, el formulario para enviar los datos al `marcador.php`.

El codigo de `formulario.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <form action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" name="nombre-jugador" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Puntos</label>
                    <input type="number" step="1" value="0" class="form-control" name="puntos-jugador" required>
                </div>
                <button id="registrar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

El `marcado.php` unicamente muestra listado de los puntos registrados.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Marcador</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            //Se ejecutaria un ciclo para ir mostrando cada valor, ya sea tomado de la bd, array o json
            <li class="list-group-item">Nombre del Jugador - +Puntos</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

La idea es ir actualizando la lista, mostrando cada uno de los registros realizados en el formularios, colocando cada nuevo registro en la parte superiro y recorrer los demas hacia abajo. Todo esto manteniedo los dos archivos abiertos y ejecutandose.

Mi primera idea fue realizarlo manteniedo los registros en una base de datos y al dar click en el *`boton registrar`* ejecutar lo siguiente en js (incluyendolo en el archivo `formulario.php`):

```
 <script>
    $(function(){
        let marcadorAbrir;
        $("#registrar").click(function(){
            if(!marcadorAbrir){
                marcadorAbrir= window.open("marcador.php");
            }else{
                marcadorAbrir.location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

****He omitido algo de codigo para no hacer tan larga la cuestion.****

Comment: Que te impide lograrlo, te da algún error?

Comment: La principal cuestion es que no logro realizar que funcione de forma adecuada, y como mencione busco una forma de enviar los datos del formulario y recibirlos en el marcador de puntos.

Comment: ¿Ya viste que el `input type="number"` se llama también `nombre-jugador`?

Comment: Por esa parte no hay problema, ya que solo fue un error al escribir mi pregunta. Gracias por la observación.